# Does 'has to' replace 'must' in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

Surely, she **must** know all my faults.

According to various dictionaries, 'have(has) to' also expresses 'certainty'.

[image]

- Michael Swan 'Practical English Usage' - OXFORD

Comment: The intended meaning of your sentence is that "she must have been blind if she does NOT know all my faults by now" or "Someone has to tell her because she needs to know"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "has to" would be fine in that sentence.

As the book points out, this is more common in American English rather than British English.

Comment: But `must` is still fine too